# Как работать с button и progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, button, progress-bar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Только начал изучать c# и не могу понять, как сделать по нажатию button загрузку progress bar?
Вот поместил на форму button, и progress bar, по нажатию на button должна происходить загрузка, но она длится одну секунду и зависает, уже и таймер добавил, и ничего не происходит, что я не так делаю помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Где код? Нужен код а не скриншот. Весь код влияющий на progressbar и код ошибки, если она есть.

Comment: Александр, пожалуйста, уберите скриншот, вместо него поставьте весь код формы.

Answer (score 1):

у вас progressbar заполняется только по нажатию кнопки, а надо примерно так

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```